# Why don't I receive a comment notification when someone inserts a space after the `@` sign?

Tags: discussion, comments, notifications

Some user used **@ harry** in a comment to respond to me, but I did not get any notification for that. I guess this is because of the space between "@" and the username. So is it possible to have notification when someone use spaces between @ and name?

Comment: how can you conform because of @ and space it is not notifying

Comment: @Damodar: may be if @ is the first character in comment.

Answer (score 12):

In my opinion such thing is not worth spending time on. You can also ask to correct typos (@Harri instead of @Harry) and there's no end to it.

There are certain rules that should be followed, and in this case those rules are very simple and clear.

I would just alert that user of his/her mistake, it's pretty rare anyway. Those who already use `@` use it well as far as I see around.

Comment: I also do the same that is tell use to do not use space between `@` and `name` next time. But what happens is sometimes user comments to notify me and I have closed tab of that question and that time I do not get notified and I lost the comment.

Comment: @Harry I understand, in such case if you want to keep track of new comments add the question to your Favorites then new comments will appear in your Favorite tab in the profile page - just check it from time to time.

Comment: not a good option cause I have to check it for many question and will result in waste in time.

Comment: @Harry not good but best you can achieve, sorry...

Answer (score 3):

Allowing a space after a @ would mean to trigger a notification, in the case @ is followed by a word that matches a username, but that in the comment is not used as username.
That is the reason I think it's preferable not to allow spaces between @ and the username.

Comment: It would not send a notification to just any user name match.  It would have to a user from the question, which it would be very rare to have it mistakenly send notifications.

Comment: @jzd Still, it would be necessary to understand if who wrote the comment added a space by a mistake, or the user meant to add the space because he was not referring to a username.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the comment notification system just ignore the space an automatically notify Harry rather than check and notify the user who is typing.

The normal rules would still apply such that notifications would only be sent if that user was already involved in the question.